# Certificate Name 'Mismatch' error

Tags: chrome, openssl

I have a self signed certificate on my Apache2 server and I am trying to get the configuration correct such that the 'Issued to:' name on the certificate matches the HTTPS address in the address bar. 
I get the following security errors:

```
The certificate for this site does not contain a Subject Alternative Name 
extension containing a domain name or IP address

There are issues with the site's certificate chain 
(net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID)
```

Please see image below.[image]

Comment: Don't connect by IP.  Set up DNS and use that

Comment: Or if its for personal use configure `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Is Kali2016 the hostname of your machine?  The Common Name field needs to be the name you will use to connect to it, either with a DNS setup like Fox said above OR by simply putting a reference in your /etc/hosts or c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (I think thati si the windows path...)

Comment: As @Fox says, configure DNS.  However, in the short term, edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add `192.168.1.6  kali2016` to the bottom.  You can then enter `https://kali2016` in the address bar of your browser.  Also, if the browser is Chrome, I believe you need to add the hostname as a Subject Alternate Name in your certificate too (as the error message implies).  This isn't really a Unix & Linux question :-)

Comment: Also the specific error message is that you don't have a Subject Alternative Name field.  This is a new requirement.  See https://textslashplain.com/2017/03/10/chrome-deprecates-subject-cn-matching/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research, I believe the problem is that most recently both Chrome (58) and Firefox (48) now require that certificates specify the hostname(s) to which they apply in the SubjectAltName field; values in the Subject field will be ignored.  More information here:  https://textslashplain.com/2017/03/10/chrome-deprecates-subject-cn-matching/.  Further, Steve Gibson does a nice just explaining this, if you want an audible explaination at around the 1:24:00 mark:  https://twit.tv/shows/security-now/episodes/610?autostart=false.

That all being said, for those creating self signed certificates, we now have an extra step to take - adding the Subject Alternate Name (SAN field).  This is all covered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl/27931596#27931596; however it is a long tread with many answers.  Basically it all boils down to the answer JWW gives, you have to create a config file containing the subjectAltName field and then  and pass it in like:

```
openssl req -config example-com.conf -new -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes \
-keyout example-com.key.pem -days 365 -out example-com.cert.pem
```

There is a nice config file example in the tread answered by JWW.  Look for: "Configuration file (passed via -config option)"

Now your certificate will have a subjectAltName and Chrome and Firefox will be happy

Answer (score -1):

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -subj "/C=US/ST=Oregon/L=Portland/O=Company Name/OU=Org/CN=www.example.com"
```

replace "subj" with the name you want

Comment: any way the certificate will not be valid (green bar) because it is not issued from a "trusted authority". You can trust your own "authority" by installing your ca root on your server as the warning say. 
As per the comments you should use a local domain /etc/hosts or similar to replace the ip address by the apropiate domain name

Answer (score -1):

I know that this isn't necessarily a proper answer to your exact question, but there likely isn't a reason for you to be self-signing certificates when [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) exists. They are a completely free certificate service and the certificates you receive will function nearly identically to ones you may get from other places (i.e. Comodo). Also, as Fox commented, don't connect by IP; if you connect to a server with SSL/TLS and it uses a certificate that doesn't contain the address that you connected to (i.e. two hostnames point to the same machine, but only one is on the cert. You connect to the one not on the cert), your browser will report the connection as insecure.